# How to change the source of python used by atom runner or script in Atom?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, atom-editor

I want to run python code with Kivy by atom-runner or script, but when I run the simple any codes with Kivy, I got ModuleNotFoundError. I checked python path by

```
import sys 
print(sys.prefix)
```

which prints ''/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7''

I guess I need to use Anaconda's python because I can run Kivy app on terminal and terminal uses python3.7 showing Anaconda.inc things.

But I can not find where to write path of python in Atom.

I tried pip install Kivy and it worked but nothing changed in Atom. And Kivy3 is in Application folder.

Just in case, my Kivy codes is this

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class IntroKivy(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text="Hello, World!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    IntroKivy().run()
```

It will be perfect if I can run this codes without using terminal as it is faster and quick.

Best